# Hide element only if it contains specific text inside, using Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I have these elements on my page:

```html
<div id="123test"><p>test</p></div>
<div id="123test"><p>othertext</p></div>
```

And I am trying to remove the `div` if it contains "test" text inside, using Java Script, but it does not seem to work.

Here is my JS:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('123test');

if (container.textContent=='test') {

container.style.display="none";

};
```

```js
var container = document.getElementById('123test');

if (container.textContent == 'test') {

  container.style.display = "none";

};
```

```html
<div id="123test"><p>test</p></div>
<div id="123test"><p>othertext</p></div>
```

I also tried using `:contains` selector way, but the result was the same. The style of the container does not change at all. What do I do wrong? Is there another approach possible? This code is a simplified version of my project, but neither of these two work. I would be very gratefull if someone would help me to overcome the issue.

Comment: Sidenote: You cannot have more than one element with the same id.

Comment: Good to know, never tried this to be honest. But even with class, problem still exists

Comment: Please do not edit your question to try to incorporate answers or learnings later. This will make it so the answers given no longer match the question content.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your HTML looks exactly like this:

```
<div id="123test"><p>test</p></div>
<!-- no whitespace or line breaks before or after <p>test</p> -->
```

and not like this

```
<div id="123test">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

To avoid this problem, call `trim()` on `container.textContent`:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('123test');

if (container.textContent.trim() == 'test') {

  container.style.display = "none";

};
```

```html
<div id="123test">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<div id="123test2">
  <p>othertext</p>
</div>
```

> And I am trying to remove the div if it contains "test" text inside, using Java Script [...]

If it is sufficient that `test` is ***contained***, check for `includes('test')` instead:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('123test');

if (container.textContent.includes('test')) {

  container.style.display = "none";

};
```

```html
<div id="123test">
  <p>test123</p>
</div>
<div id="123test2">
  <p>othertext</p>
</div>
```

Important sidenote: **You cannot have more than one element with the same `id`.**

Sidenote 2: `:contains` only exists in jQuery, not in CSS.

Sidenote 3 about using `innerText`: This had been my first approach, but for some strange reason on Safari/MacOS it won't hide the container:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('123test');

if (container.innerText == 'test') {

  container.style.display = "none";

};

console.log(container.innerText.length); // 6 (!) on Safari/MacOS
```

```html
<div id="123test">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<div id="123test2">
  <p>othertext</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I corrected my mistake with multiple ids. But when I use trim or includes, code still does not work. Could you please show me a working snippet?

Comment: This answer has two working snippets. Your problem with iterating a number of divs which share a common `class` is a different problem and thus I didn't deal with it aside of fixing the duplicate id problem. You need to loop over a `NodeList` to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of checking an arbitrary DOM tree for text nodes that contain the string `"test"` and then hiding them by setting `display: none;`.

The function `hideTestNodes` accepts [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and primarily makes use of [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) and [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper')

const hideTestNodes = (children) => {
  for (const child of children) {
    if (child.nodeType === 1) {
      // If the node is another Element, check its child nodes
      hideTestNodes(child.childNodes)
    }
 
    // If the node is a text node and the content includes 'test'
    // then hide the parent element containing the text node
    if (child.nodeType === 3 && /test/i.test(child.textContent)) {
      child.parentElement.style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
}

hideTestNodes(wrapper.childNodes)
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>some other text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <p>some deeply <span> nested test</span> text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>this <span>includes</span> test.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that to only one specific div, then it's very simple:

NOTE: I added two seconds to let you see how it happens. you can remove the timer.

```js
 let test1 = document.getElementById("test1");

  if (test1.innerHTML.includes("test")) {

    setTimeout(() => {

      test1.style.display = "none";
      
    }, 2000);
    
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="test1"><p>test</p></div>
  <div id="test2"><p>othertext</p></div>
</div>
```

If you want to check all divs, it's still simple and you just need to make an `array` from them then use `forEach loop` to check all divs in that container:

```js
let divs = document.getElementById("container").children;

[...divs].forEach(div => {
  if (div.textContent.includes("test")) {

    setTimeout(() => {

      div.style.display = "none";

    }, 2000);

  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="test1"><p>test</p></div>
  <div id="test2"><p>othertext</p></div>
</div>
```